# In mutil TypeScript projects. How do I prevent one project import internal modules from another project?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have to projects structured like this:

```
├── proj_1
│   ├── hidden
│   │   └── hidden-class.mts
│   ├── index.mts
│   ├── visible-class.mts
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── proj_2
    ├── main.mts
    └── tsconfig.json
```

The tsconfig.json of proj_1 is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "composite": true // build proj_1 as a lib
  },
  "references": [],
  "include": ["*", "**/*"],
}
```

And the one for proj_2:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "composite": true,
    "paths": {
      // I only want to expose a single file from proj_1 to proj_2
      "~/proj_1/index.mjs": ["../proj_1/index.mjs"]
    }
  },
  "references": [
    {
      // path mapping
      "path": "../proj_1/"
    }
  ],
  "include": ["*", "**/*"],
}
```

Then I found I could write such code, which is not expected:

```
// proj_1/index.mts
// Only export `VisibleClass` and other project should only import this file.
export { VisibleClass } from "./visible-class.mjs";



// proj_2/main.mts
import { VisibleClass } from "~/proj_1/index.mjs";
// This line should be error. How do I prevent this path from importing?
import { HiddenClass } from "../proj_1/hidden/hidden-class.mjs";

const v = new VisibleClass();

// This line should be error
const h = new HiddenClass();
```

As the code tells I don't want the `HiddenClass` to be exported but it could actually. I don't know how to prevent that.

Comment: You need to use `package.json` `exports` to limit exports

Comment: @Dimava Could you please provide some links or examples?

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/f36c49f31b658985542de1f5f1f269f2f8b63132/packages/vue/package.json#L22

Comment: @Dimava Thanks for the link. Does that mean I need to add a `package.json` the each project, which I didn't? I have this structure followed by the doc https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html which hasn't anything about the `package.json`. I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, you add it as `"name": "@me/my-package" "dependencies: { "@me/my-lib": "workspace:*" }` and import it as `import from '@me/my-lib'`

Comment: https://github.com/rhyek/typescript-monorepo-example

Comment: Do that mean I should make proj_1 as a local package and refer it in package approach rather to use tsconfig.json to refer it?

Comment: tscongig references are for "make the implementation files  unable to import the test files of the same package". If you have a lib and an app this most likely should be different packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tsconfig.json` references are for "make the implementation files unable to import the test files of the same package".
If you have a lib and an app this most likely should be different packages in a monorepo

Here's roughly how that could look like:

```json
{
  "name": "vue",
  "main": "index.js",
  "module": "dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js",
  "types": "dist/vue.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./dist/vue.d.mts",
        "node": "./index.mjs",
        "default": "./dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js"
      },
      "require": {
        "types": "./dist/vue.d.ts",
        "default": "./index.js"
      }
    },
    "./server-renderer": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./server-renderer/index.d.mts",
        "default": "./server-renderer/index.mjs"
      },
      "require": {
        "types": "./server-renderer/index.d.ts",
        "default": "./server-renderer/index.js"
      }
    },
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/shared": "workspace:*"
  }
}
```

`exports` will limit what you are able to `import {} from 'vue/....'` in this case

You may check https://github.com/vuejs/core/tree/main/packages/vue or https://github.com/rhyek/typescript-monorepo-example for an example of TS monorepo